# Matrix representations of Lie groups of type $B_n$

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

For the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(2n+1, \mathbb{C})$, there is a matrix representation given by the following matrices:
\begin{align}
\left( \begin{matrix} 0 & x & y \\ -y^T & A & B \\ -x^T & C & -A^T \end{matrix} \right),
\end{align}
where $x, y$ are $1 \times n$ matrices, $A,B,C$ are $n \times n$ matrices. Are there similar matrix representations for Lie group $\mathrm{SO}(2n+1, \mathbb{C})$? Thank you very much.

Edit: I forgot to mention that $B,C$ are skew-symmetric, $B=-B^T, C=-C^T$.

Comment: It depends on what 'similar' means—this is the differential of an embedding $\operatorname{SO}(2n + 1, \mathbb C) \to \operatorname{GL}(2n + 1, \mathbb C)$.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @LSpice, yes, maybe this is what I am looking for. Do you have some references about this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quadratic form whose matrix is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & I_n \\ 0 & I_n & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ gives an embedding of $\operatorname{SO}(2n + 1, \mathbb C)$ in $\operatorname{GL}(2n + 1, \mathbb C)$ whose derivative is your specified embedding $\mathfrak{so}(2n + 1, \mathbb C) \to \mathfrak{gl}(2n + 1, \mathbb C)$.  Under this embedding,

- $\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & A & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & A^{-\mathsf T} \end{pmatrix}\mathrel: \text{$A$ diagonal}\right\}$ is the image of a maximal (algebraic) torus in $\operatorname{SO}(2n + 1, \mathbb C)$,
- the image of a maximal unipotent subgroup of $\operatorname{SO}(2n + 1, \mathbb C)$ is generated by

  - $\exp\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & E_{ij} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -E_{ji} \end{pmatrix}$, where $i$ is less than $j$,
    and
  - $\exp\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & y \\ -y^{\mathsf T} & 0 & B \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, where $B$ is skew-symmetric,
    and
- the image of the Tits subgroup of $\operatorname{SO}(2n + 1, \mathbb C)$ is generated by

  - $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & A & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & A^{-\mathsf T} \end{pmatrix}$, where $A = I - E_{ii} - E_{jj} + E_{ij} - E_{ji}$ with $i \ne j$,
    and
  - $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & D' & D'' \\ 0 & D'' & D' \end{pmatrix}$, where $D'$ and $D''$ are diagonal $(0, 1)$-matrices such that $D' + D'' = I_n$.

(I originally made a comment to this effect, but I had the wrong quadratic form, and wrongly suggested that you had switched $x^{\mathsf T}$ and $y^{\mathsf T}$ in your embedding.)

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! I forgot to mention in the question that $B, C$ are skew-symmetric: $B=-B^T, C=-C^T$.

Comment: And I forgot to mention [it](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408298/matrix-representations-of-lie-groups-of-type-b-n/408326#comment1047348_408326) in my answer, but have now edited to correct that.

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: I have a question about your notation $A^{-T}$. Does it mean $(A^{-1})^T$? Thank you very much.

Comment: [Yes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408298/matrix-representations-of-lie-groups-of-type-b-n/408326#comment1047352_408326).

Comment: thank you very much!